# Need to know how to kill background process in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, background-service

I'm creating a background process in iOS to send location updates to a server, but I'm having trouble controlling it from the main application. Mostly, I'm having trouble killing the service. My app uses a button that start/stops the background process, and also figuring out if the process is still running.

I'm using two methods in a class, a StartListening uses a timer to start location updates, and StopListening that kills the timer. But the I can't always kill the background process, especially if the app has been switched off. I don't have the problem with Android since the API takes care of starting and stopping the location process, but iOS, I have to do this manually.

```
    public void StartListening()
    {
         //class setup here

        if(CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.DesiredAccuracy = 10;
            locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();
            taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() =>
           {
               this.timer.Dispose();
           });

            timer = new Timer(async (o) => 
            {
                CLLocation location = null;
                while(location == null)
                {
                    location = locationManager.Location;
                }
                if (location != null)
                {
                    //handle location

                }


            }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(UpdateInterval));
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
        }
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {

        this.locationManager.StopUpdatingLocation();
        if(taskId != 0)
        {
            if (this.timer != null)
            {
                this.timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                this.timer.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm expecting the StopLocation to stop the background process, and in testing, it works fine, but when I actually try to use the app for a while, it seems it'll "forget" about the background process and not kill it properly. Does anyone have a suggestion on why this is/how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no "background process" on iOS. You should only call `beginBackgroundTask` when your app is about to be suspended (ie it is already in the background state) and you need some extra time (up to 180 seconds). You also don't need a timer.  When you start location updates you will get periodic calls to the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method. Here you can send your data to the server.  You can check the interval since the last update if you don't want to send each second.

Comment: @user2850818 you can find answers here. Please check the link - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41002/kill-background-process Xamarin related questions please ask in https://forums.xamarin.com

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code

```
if(CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)
    {
        locationManager.DesiredAccuracy = 10;
        locationManager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();
        locationManager.AllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = false;
        locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();
        //...
    }
```

**RequestWhenInUseAuthorization** only works when the foreground operation mode is switched to the background operation mode. For example, if the App switches to the background operation mode, the agent method `didUpdateLocations` will not continue.

And do not forget add the privacy in info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>xxxx</string>
```